# Update TextView with WiFi Signal Strength. Android Studio. Writing in Java

Tags: java, loops, textview, android-studio-3.0

I am getting several errors and can't discover which is causing the problem.

***Errors:***

- Cannot resolve symbol
- Unexpected Token (while loop)
- Unknown class "x"

**How can I set the textView to display the wifiSignal strength?**

Sorry for not narrowing down the problem more, but I am new to developing in android studio and am too lost to  be specific.

***Thanks so much for any help you can provide!***

Code:

```
package com.example.a18lts01.wificompass;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    } }

    class wifi
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }

        int x = 1;
        while(x == 1)
        {
            int signalLevel = result.level;
            TextView.setText(signalLevel + "db");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
            myThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `result` variable? Why code starting from `int x= 1...` isn't in any method?  It looks like just no matching braces... And next time you post code here use CTRL + ALT + L in android studio...

Comment: While editing your code, I noticed that your while loop was messed up.  In the while loop you had x = 1 which would assign x to be 1 instead of checking to see if x == 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got some misplaced brackets. I'm assuming you want your `int x = 1;` etc. to be inside the `run()` method? Currently you have an empty `run()` method.

Double-check the placement of the brackets. It looks like you need to remove the `}` a couple of lines after `public void run() {`, and add a `}` at the end of the `wifi` class.